# For which values of p and q does an improper integral converge

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am to find for which values of p and q the following integral converges:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\,dx\quad (q>0)$$

As I tested the limit of the above function with $\frac{x^p}{x^q}$, and found it was $1$, I let myself separate the boundaries from $0$ to $1$, and from $1$ to infinity of the later function.

From $0$ to $1$ it's a normal integral, that leaves us to check what the divergence of the integral from $1$ to infinity, which by the comparison test happens as $q>$$1$+$p$

Thanks for the quick replay.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^1\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\,dx$ is proper, and thus converges for all values of $p,q$.

Comment: I failed to notice that. That leaves us with q>p+1?

Comment: That should be correct.

Comment: Thanks. I should edit it.

Comment: I believe that if $p<0$ than that is not true.

Comment: Ugh.  I can't believe I missed that.  Yes, if $p\lt0$, then $\int_0^1\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\,dx$ diverges

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* : Use the fact that $\zeta(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}$ diverges for $k\leqslant1\iff k=q-p>1$ .